# Redirect links using PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, pdo

Hello guys how are you doing?

I'm working on a project using PDO statements, and I want to redirect the user to a certain URL where it brings it from the DB, but the browser gives me an error while redirecting.. and if I type a certain website into my code it redirects without any problem.

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['r']) || !empty($_GET['r']))
{
        $l_url = $_GET['r'];

        $con = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO links (url) VALUE (?)");
        $con->execute(array($_POST['url']));

        header("location:" .$l_url);
        exit();
}
```

if I type any URL after "location" it'll redirect without any problems, but not with this here.

Error:

> Firefox - "The page isn’t redirecting properly" in Firefox and " This
>   page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times." in
>   Chrome and I did clear the session & Cookies

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "The page isn’t redirecting properly" in Firefox and " This page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times." in Chrome and I did clear the session & Cookies.

Comment: what is $l_url value? and why (isset($_GET['r']) || !empty($_GET['r'])) and not  (isset($_GET['r']) && !empty($_GET['r'])) ?

Comment: The value of $l_url is as same as the one on DB, which means it's correct.
Also, I've changed the if statement to &&.

Answer (score 1):

```
isset($_GET['r']) || !empty($_GET['r'])
```

Unnecessary code, you can change the above expression to the following:

```
!empty($_GET['r'])
```

About your question:

> but the browser gives me an error while redirecting..

What error message are you receiving? Without this information I cannot help, but probably variable `$_POST['url']` does not exist.

Comment: if I remove " isset .. etc" it'll redirect automatically but my code requires users to Click a specific URL before redirecting.

the Error message says: "The page isn’t redirecting properly" in Firefox
and " This page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times." in Chrome

and I did clear the session & Cookies.

Comment: No, you can remove, because you're checking the same variable 2 times. I'm almost sure variable `$_POST['url']` does not exist, try execute `var_dump($_POST); exit;` to debug

Comment: The output is : " array(0){} " that's mean its empty. What should I do?